# Why the cargo run command throws me OS Error 13 on Linux?

Tags: rust, archlinux, partition, rust-cargo

I've created a `Rust` project with `cargo` in an external `NTFS` partition on `Arch Linux`.
When I run `cargo build` the command works, but if I run the `cargo run` command, cargo throws me the following error:

```
[myuser@myuser myproject]$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.03s
     Running `target/debug/myproject`
error: could not execute process `target/debug/myproject` (never executed)

Caused by:
  Permission denied (os error 13)
```

I believe that the error might have been caused due to the partition's permissions. Here is my mounting configuration in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=XXXXXXX                   /path/to/mountpoint ntfs-3g         defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names         0 0
```

A similar error can be found [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6757).

What could be the cause of that problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS does not support Linux permissions, and as such it is impossible to execute a file stored on NTFS. Keep your project on a file system designed for Linux, such as ext4, to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS can be configured to allow software execution if you follow the steps as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245154/how-to-get-permissions-to-execute-programs-from-ntfs-hard-drive).